# Android: Reference to Activity object in another class becomes NULL

Tags: java, android, android-intent

What i am trying to do is to pass a reference to the mainactivity to another class and use it.

when i first pass the reference it is not null. but later when i use it in an event handler it becomes null.

here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity implements SmsReceivedListener {
    SmsReceiver smsreceiver = new SmsReceiver();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        smsreceiver.setSmsReceivedListener(this);
    }

    public void drawme() {
        // do smth
    }

    @Override
    public void onSmsReceived(String id, String lon, String lat) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

The other class where I obtain the reference:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private SmsReceivedListener listener;
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        // Here it is NULL
        if(listener!=null)
            listener().onSmsReceived(carNumber, lon,lat);
    }

    public void setSmsReceivedListener(SmsReceivedListener mainActivity) {
        //It is no null when I first set the object here
        listener = (mainActivity);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you register your sms receiver?

Comment: This code can't even compile! You omit the essential parts of your class code - therefore we can only guess.

Comment: for what  u r using the refernce  ??

Comment: If you're registering your SMSReceiver in its own constructor, it'll be registered long before the listener is set.

Answer (score 1):

It will only "become" null if you

- set it to null
- use it in a way which is not thread safe and you are reading in a different thread to setting
- you are using the same field, but in a different object.

Answer (score 1):

You are not registering the SmsReceiver, therefor i guess the following :

The SmsReceiver is registered in the Manifest. Therefore, an instance of the receiver is created by the system when the broadcast is detected, and it is not the same instance as the one you create.

Suggestion : register the receiver in the activity, not in the manifest.

Comment: yes i registered it in manifest. so you mean i should do the following:
SmsReceiver smsreceiver = new SmsReceiver;
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

  registerReceiver(smsreceiver, filter);

Comment: To further elaborate on this answer, in most cases, you do not want to tie a specific instance of an Activity to a BroadcastReceiver. The correct way of doing that, only allows for the BroadcastReceiver to work while the activity is open. The incorrect way may allow it to still work, but you risk memory leaks and seemingly random exceptions.

Comment: If you want the BroadcastReceiver to always be active, like it would be when you register it in the manifest. You should continue to register it in the manifest. But dealing with your activity will need to be done via another BroadcastReceiver specifically for communicating from the SMSReceiver to your Activity. I would Broadcast a new Intent stating that you just received a new SMS and if nothing catches that status Intent, you can launch the activity to bring it to the front. If you give us a better idea of what's going on, we might be able to better tell you which method is more suited.

Comment: @Mikedg : regarding the last part of the comment, it can be implemented using a singleTask activity that would be started by the BR, and the activity would either start or receive onNewIntent.

Comment: @njzk2 google point. If we had more insight into the use case, it would be much easier to help guide him towards a correct implementation.