# Java include snippet in different class files?

Tags: java, android

I wrote a listener that does some actions onKeyDown basically I need to include it in all my activities but I'm new to Java and don't know the best way to do it, I can of course just copy paste the code on every class but it would be a pain to keep every one updated.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("pref_disable_keydowns", true)) {
        System.out.println("Prevent keydown");
        return true; 
        }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

How can I include this in different .java files so I only have to modify it once to affect all classes it's included?

Comment: and how do I extend my classA to classB when it already extends Activity (`public class MainActivity extends Activity`)

Comment: You cannot extend more than one class in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not never under (nearly) no circumstances copy code from one method to another.

Now to your solution:

```
public class MyListerer implement KeyListener {

    public void onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hey world!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Now you can make

```
object.addKeyListener(new MyListener());
```

I am pretty sure, that the Interface `KeyListener` may have a different Name, but I think you get the point.

**update**

Is it all about Android Activities? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

In that case you can implement it a different way. There is no event-listener in Android activites. You can do the following:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MyListener delegate= new MyListener();

    // your existing code

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        delegate.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I've been reading about interfaces but I'm not sure how to implement it. I created a class called MyListener and an Interface called KeyListener. I don't understand why the methods are defined in the class. How will I use these methods on another class?

Comment: @Liso22  you could take a look at my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388498/how-do-i-manipulate-a-view-from-another-class-in-android/14388732#14388732, which shows a complete example of defining and using an Interface

Comment: I don't get why they ton use the Listener-Pattern in Android. I think it is better to read understand.. Or did they have Apps with only one Activity in mind?

Comment: I updated my question to show how I tried to implement your code.

Comment: I just saw your edit, what should be the content of MyListener?

Comment: The same as written before the update. My edit was about how to call the Listener from your Activity. I did not see, that this was about Android Activities, where the Listener pattern is not used.

Comment: btw... "There is noch event-listener..." yeah! we germans really know how to mix languages :D just a hint :)

Comment: No mixing, I speak Denglisch :)

Comment: I just implemented it. I'm only having one problem, It seems class MyListener has to be in the same package as MainActivity. Is it possible to implement it from a different package?